# Vector not clearing correctly

Tags: c++, vector, tuples

I'm having a problem clearing a vector of vectors.

I use a tuple function to return multiple variables.

I call to the tuple function twice in succession (using a different file each time).

When I check the outputs from the function, I get the equivalent of

`vector1.size = vector1.size` 
and
        `vector2.size = (vector1.size + vector2.size)`

rather than 
`vector1.size= vector1.size` and `vector2.size = vector2.size`.

This leads me to believe that **somewhere** a vector is not being correctly cleared between the function calls, and that this is causing the second output to be written on top of the first output.

Below is my code:

main() and declarations

```
tuple<vector<float>, vector<vector<float>>, int> ReadFile(string fileToBeRead);

vector<float> sadInterpolationStorage;
vector<vector<float>> sadInterpolationVectorStorage;
vector<float> userInterpolationStorage;
vector<vector<float>> userInterpolationVectorStorage;
int sadAnimationLength;
int inputAnimationLength;

int main() {

    tie(sadInterpolationStorage, sadInterpolationVectorStorage, sadAnimationLength) = ReadFile(sadWalkCycleMocapFile);

    tie(userInterpolationStorage, userInterpolationVectorStorage, inputAnimationLength) = ReadFile(inputMocapFile);

cout << sadInterpolationVectorStorage[1].size() << endl;
cout << userInterpolationVectorStorage[1].size() << endl;


return 0;
 }
```

`userInterpolationVectorStorage[1].size()` will always be equal to the sum of
   `(sadInterpolationVectorStorage[1].size()+ sadInterPolationVectorStorage[1].size()`. **It seems like a vector is not being cleared somewhere**, but in `ReadFile()` I create new variables for everything.

ReadFile()

```
tuple<vector<float>, vector<vector<float>>, int> ReadFile(string fileToBeRead) {
string firstLineInFile;
string secondLineInFile;
string thirdLineInFile;
vector<float> interpolationStorage;
vector<vector<float>> interpolationVectorStorage; 
int animationLength = 0;
vector<vector<float>> vectorStorage;

//Create a vector to hold all the mocap data values in float form.
vector<float> floatTokens;
//Create a vector to hold an entire frame (the data and the words).
vector<string> oneFrame;

//Create an input file stream
ifstream in(fileToBeRead, ios::in);
//cases to handle the first 3 lines of the file (first 3 lines contain no data, but are necessary)
//extracts each line into an object and writes them to the top of the output file
getline(in, firstLineInFile);
getline(in, secondLineInFile);
getline(in, thirdLineInFile);


//loop until the end of the file is reached
while (in.eof() == 0) {

    //create a buffer to store each frame
    stringstream buffer;
    //write the frameID to the file.
    extractFrameID(in);
    //loop around the 29 lines in a frame, push each line into the vector.
    for (int i = 0; i < 29; i++) {
        string tempString;
        getline(in, tempString);

        //if the end of the file is reached (.empty() is used as the last line in the mocap file is always an empty line.
        if (tempString.empty()) {

#pragma region Storing all data vectors in a vector
            vectorStorage.push_back(rootXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(rootZVector);

            vectorStorage.push_back(lowerBackXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lowerBackYVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lowerBackZVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(upperBackXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(upperBackYVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(upperBackZVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(thoraxXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(thoraxYVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(thoraxZVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lowerNeckXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lowerNeckYVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lowerNeckZVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(upperNeckXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(upperNeckYVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(upperNeckZVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(headXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(headYVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(headZVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(rClavicleYVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(rClavicleZVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(rHumerusXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(rHumerusYVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(rHumerusZVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(rRadiusXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(rWristYVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(rHandXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(rHandYVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(rFingersXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(rThumbXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(rThumbZVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lClavicleYVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lClavicleZVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lHumerusXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lHumerusYVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lHumerusZVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lRadiusXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lWristYVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lHandXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lHandYVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lFingersXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lThumbXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lThumbZVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(rFemurXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(rFemurYVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(rFemurZVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(rTibiaXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(rFootXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(rFootZVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(rToesXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lFemurXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lFemurYVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lFemurZVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lTibiaXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lFootXVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lFootZVector);
            vectorStorage.push_back(lToesXVector);
#pragma endregion   
            //loop for every data type, 58 or so
            for (size_t i = 0; i < vectorStorage.size(); i++) {
                //interpolate between each data value and store the result in a vector.
                //loop for every data value of every data type , 227 or so (1 per frame).
                for (size_t j = 1; j < vectorStorage[i].size(); j++)
                {

                    interpolationStorage.push_back(vectorStorage[i][j] - vectorStorage[i][j - 1]);

                }
                interpolationVectorStorage.push_back(interpolationStorage);
                interpolationStorage.clear();

            }   
            vectorStorage.clear();

            cout << "Reading of " << fileToBeRead << " completed" << endl;

            return make_tuple(interpolationStorage, interpolationVectorStorage, animationLength);
        }
        oneFrame.push_back(tempString);
    }

    //populate the buffer with the vector.
    copy(oneFrame.begin(), oneFrame.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(buffer, "\n"));

    //split the buffer up into tokens(objects) and store them into a vector 
    vector<string> mainTokenVector = split(buffer.str(), ' ');

    //defining  vectors.
    vector<float> floatTokenVector;
    vector<string> stringTokenVector;

    //loop to split up the token vector into strings and floats, and store them in vectors
    for (size_t i = 0; i < mainTokenVector.size(); i++) {
        //if the token is a string, put it in the string vector
        if (isFloat(mainTokenVector[i]) == 0) {
            stringTokenVector.push_back(mainTokenVector[i]);
        }
        //if the token is a float, put it in the float vector
        else if (isFloat(mainTokenVector[i]) == 1) {
            floatTokenVector.push_back(stof(mainTokenVector[i]));
        }

    }

#pragma region Pushing data values to vectors
    //pushing all data values to their responding vectors in order to interpolate between them later.

    rootXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[0]);
    rootZVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[2]);

    lowerBackXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[6]);
    lowerBackYVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[7]);
    lowerBackZVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[8]);
    upperBackXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[9]);
    upperBackYVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[10]);
    upperBackZVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[11]);
    thoraxXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[12]);
    thoraxYVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[13]);
    thoraxZVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[14]);
    lowerNeckXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[15]);
    lowerNeckYVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[16]);
    lowerNeckZVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[17]);
    upperNeckXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[18]);
    upperNeckYVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[19]);
    upperNeckZVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[20]);
    headXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[21]);
    headYVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[22]);
    headZVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[23]);
    rClavicleYVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[24]);
    rClavicleZVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[25]);
    rHumerusXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[26]);
    rHumerusYVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[27]);
    rHumerusZVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[28]);
    rRadiusXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[29]);
    rWristYVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[30]);
    rHandXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[31]);
    rHandYVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[32]);
    rFingersXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[33]);
    rThumbXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[34]);
    rThumbZVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[35]);
    lClavicleYVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[36]);
    lClavicleZVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[37]);
    lHumerusXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[38]);
    lHumerusYVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[39]);
    lHumerusZVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[40]);
    lRadiusXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[41]);
    lWristYVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[42]);
    lHandXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[43]);
    lHandYVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[44]);
    lFingersXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[45]);
    lThumbXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[46]);
    lThumbZVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[47]);
    rFemurXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[48]);
    rFemurYVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[49]);
    rFemurZVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[50]);
    rTibiaXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[51]);
    rFootXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[52]);
    rFootZVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[53]);
    rToesXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[54]);
    lFemurXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[55]);
    lFemurYVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[56]);
    lFemurZVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[57]);
    lTibiaXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[58]);
    lFootXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[59]);
    lFootZVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[60]);
    lToesXVector.push_back(floatTokenVector[61]);
#pragma endregion

    //clear the vectors to prepare them for the next frame.
    oneFrame.clear();
    mainTokenVector.clear();
    stringTokenVector.clear();
    floatTokenVector.clear();
    animationLength++;
}
//close the file currently associated with the object, disassociating it from the stream.
in.close();
```

}

I've spent the past few hours trying to figure out why this is happening, with no success, so any help at all would be greatly appreciated. If you have any queries let me know.
Cheers!

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: I've tried debugging the code, but with no success in finding the solution to this one. I can't pinpoint where `vector2` is being set to `vector1 + vector2`.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

I had declared all the body vectors( `lowerBackXVector`
           `lowerBackYVector`
           `lowerBackZVector`) etc outside the function, therefore they were not getting reset. I defined them within the function and now it works perfectly. Thanks guys.